# heterogeneous kubernetes cluster, container performance difference

Tags: performance, kubernetes, containers, heterogeneous

Suppose there is a k8s cluster which is made up of **nodes of different hardware specs**.

Then 2 pods are allocated to 2 different nodes.

Suppose the container in the pod had specified **1000m cpu**.

Could the two containers running on those 2 different nodes show different levels of performance?

To ask more directly: in a heterogeneous k8s cluster, could containers perform differently(iops, cpu, mem, etc) due to which node it happens to be allocated to?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. If two Pods both specify e.g. 1000m CPU and they run on different nodes, they both get an equivalent of 1 CPU core on their node. If one node has a faster CPU than the other node, then the Pod on this node correspondingly runs faster.

The same applies for other hardware characteristics of the nodes, e.g. the availability of a GPU, the speed of the memory and cache, etc.

If you want a more deterministic behaviour, you can categorise your nodes with labels or assign [taints](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/taint-and-toleration/) to them. Then, on the Pod side, you can influence  what node a Pod gets scheduled to with [tolerations](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/taint-and-toleration/), [node selectors](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#nodeselector), [node affinities](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#node-affinity), or even a [custom scheduler](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/extend-kubernetes/configure-multiple-schedulers/).